# singularity of tangent cone and tangent cone of singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

The book I am using is Chirka's Complex Analytic Set.

Suppose A is a complex analytic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ containing $0$ as a singular point. The tangent cone $
c(A,0)$ of $A$ at $0$ is the set of all vectors $v$ such that there exists $a_j\in A$ and $t_j>0$ such that $a_j\to 0$ and $t_ja_j\to v$.

$C(A,0)$ is a homogeneous algebraic variety. It is the common zeros of the leading terms of holomorphic functions vanishing on $A$.

My question is: As an analytic set, $C(A,0)$ itself has singularities. So is there any relation between $sgn C(A,0)$ and $C(sgn(A),0)$?(Assuming $0$ is a singularity of $A$) For example, is one included in the other? If neither inclusion holds in general, then is there any condition that ensures one side of inclusion?

I am in functional analysis but my research concerns analytic subsets. I will appreciate it if any one can explain this in a relatively analytic way.

Thank You!

Comment: What happens if $A$ is has equation $x^2+y^2=0$? And if $A$ is $x^2-y^3=0$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez then the corresponding cones are defined by $x^2+y^2=0$ and $x^2=0$. See Proposition 1 on page 83 of Chirka's book.

Comment: Well, if that s the case then the definition of cone you are using is not the one you described in the question! In any case, what relation is there in those cases between sng C(A,0) and C(sgn A,0)?